# how to write Feature Test for -excel document upload check

Tags: laravel, tdd

i'm using https://docs.laravel-excel.com/ for uploading Excel and then display on view

here is my controller

```
public function import() 
    {
        $rows= Excel::toArray(new ProfitAndLosImport, request()->file('pl'));
        return view("pl")->with(compact('rows'));
    }
```

how to write test for checking this process ?
Any help would be much appreciated

i'm using this but it's working

```
   public function testUpload()
    {
        Excel::fake();
        $this->actingAs(factory('App\User')->create());
        $testFile = UploadedFile::fake()->create('borrowers.xlsx');
        $response =$this->post('pl',['pl'=>$testFile]);
       Excel::assertImported('create_terms.xls', function(ProfitAndLosImport $import) {
        return true;
        });
    }
```